# Smoothing function to combine a polynomial and a constant

Tags: polynomials, smooth-functions, step-function

[click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9dIa.jpg)

I have below function:

$y=0$ for $x<=0.12$ and

$y=80((x/0.12)^8-1)$ for $x>0.12$

I need to smooth out the transition between these two functions. Can I find out the best transition function to fit these two equations?

Comment: If you can define, clearly and unambiguously, what you mean by "best transition", then we can probably work out a suitable answer.

Comment: Take your favorite "*best transition*" approximation $\,h(x)\,$ of the [unit step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) function, then define $f(x) = \left(1-h(x-0.12)\right)\,f_-(x) + h(x-0.12) f_+(x)\,$.

Comment: Sorry for the unambiguity. Looking for a functional form (i.e., polynomial) to avoid the sharp corner at $x=0.12$ (black line in the image attached). I have tried a linear and a polynomial combination (blue line), but that poorly captures the variation at low $x$.

Comment: Still ambiguous. What exactly does "poorly captures the variation at low $x$" mean?